# Lapply to execute command for a list of variables

Tags: r, lapply

I intend to change the order of levels of some factors.
The intention is to apply this command

```
Df$X1 <- ordered(Df$X1, levels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1"))
```

to a list of variables (X1 to X2)

```
        Df <- data.frame(
  X1 = ordered(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
  X2 = ordered(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
  X3 = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
  Y = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T))
)

tmplistporadove <- as.list(paste("Df$",names(Df)[1:2],sep=""))
zmena <- lapply(tmplistporadove, function(x) substitute(x <- ordered(x, levels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1")))   )
eval(zmena)
```

But R just prints this:

```
X[[i]] <- ordered(X[[i]], levels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1"))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't run `Df[1:2] <- lapply(Df[1:2], function(x) ordered(x, levels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1")))`? (or slightly shorter `Df[1:2] <- lapply(Df[1:2], ordered, levels = 5:1)`)

Comment: or to do it by name, `ind <- c('X1', 'X2') ; Df[ind] <- lapply(Df[ind],...)`